# GWT google-gin field injection not working

Tags: java, gwt, guice

I'm trying to get field injecting to work in google-gin, but when I call TestClass.test() the injected field is null. What am I doing wrong? According to the docs field injection should be really straight forward. Is there anything I'm missing in the ContextModule class?

```java
public class MainEntry implements EntryPoint {
    private final ContextInjector injector = GWT.create(ContextInjector.class);
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        injector.getAppMain();
    }
}

@GinModules(ContextModule.class)
public interface ContextInjector extends Ginjector {
    AppMain getAppMain();
}

public class MyLogger {
}

public class ContextModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyLogger.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}

public class AppMain {
    @Inject
    AppMain(MyLogger logger) {
        // logger is injected properly here
        new TestClass().test();
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    @Inject
    private MyLogger logger;

    public void test() {
        // logger is null here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TestClass` is not managed by GIN, so GIN won't inject anything in it. You have to either let GIN instantiate `TestClass` (e.g. change `MyLogger` to `TestClass` in your `AppMain` constructor, and call `test()` on the given instance), or ask GIN to inject an existing `TestClass` instance's members (add a method to your `Ginjector` that takes a `TestClass` as argument, when called, it'll inject fields and methods of the passed-in instance).